# How to call API when submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the API and Login form, separately. Now I want to send my login credentials to API.

i don't know about how to call API and return data. `const handleSubmit = (e) => {}` inside of this, how to call API?

```
//login page

const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
  username: "",
  password: ""
});

export function LoginForm(props) {
  const { switchToSignup } = useContext(AccountContext);
  const [formData, updateFormData] = React.useState(initialFormData);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    updateFormData({
      ...formData,
      //whitespace
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim()
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(formData);
    this.props.history.push('/auth')
  };

return (

<BoxContainer className="mobiview">
     <FormContainer>
        <Input type="text" placeholder="User name" name="username" onChange={handleChange}/>
        <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" onChange={handleChange}/>
     </FormContainer>
     <SubmitButton type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Signin</SubmitButton>
</BoxContainer>
```

```
//API (Its in another folder)

export const authProvider = {
  // authentication
  login: ({ username, password }) => {
    const request = new Request(url + "/auth", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
      headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }),
    });

           ...
           ...

  }
}
```

Comment: Try using fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene I have the login credentials, but i dont know how to send that data to api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the auth file, invoke from `handleSubmit`

```
import authProvider from "./path-to-file";

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(formData);
    const { username, password } = formData;
    authProvider.login({
       username, 
       password
    });
  };
```